# Dynamic text input with HTML output

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I need to display the data entered into several text fields using div elements. There should be a dedicated div for each text input.

I have looked around all I have found is how to create dynamic inputs. But none of them explains how to use the created fields to read the info and display the info

```js
function display_array()
{
   var e = "<hr/>";   
    
   for (var y=0; y<array.length; y++)
   {
     e += "Element " + y + " = " + array[y] + "<br/>";
   }
   document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = e;
}
//Counter to maintain number of textboxes and give them unique id for later reference
var intTextBox = 0;

/**
* Function to add textbox element dynamically
* First we incrementing the counter and creating new div element with unique id
* Then adding new textbox element to this div and finally appending this div to main content.
*/
function addElement() {
    intTextBox++;
    var objNewDiv = document.createElement('div');
    objNewDiv.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + intTextBox);
    objNewDiv.innerHTML = 'Textbox ' + intTextBox + ': <input type="text" id="tb_' + intTextBox + '" name="tb_' + intTextBox + '"/>';
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(objNewDiv);
}

/**
* Function to remove textbox element dynamically
* check if counter is more than zero then remove the div element with the counter id and reduce the counter
* if counter is zero then show alert as no existing textboxes are there
*/
function removeElement() {
    if(0 < intTextBox) {
        document.getElementById('content').removeChild(document.getElementById('div_' + intTextBox));
        intTextBox--;
    } else {
        alert("No textbox to remove");
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Demo of adding and removing textboxes dynamically using simple JavaScript</p>
<p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addElement();">Add</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeElement();">Remove</a>
</p>
<div id="content"></div>


<input type="button" id="button2" value="Display" onclick="display_array();"></input>
<div id="Result"></div>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what the question is.

Comment: Update question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i give you 3 changes and not sure if that is what you want,see this demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/xianshenglu/ev1f38L3/

first change: add var array,,,,

```
var array=document.getElementsByClassName('tb');
```

second，add .value

```
 e += "Element " + y + " = " + array[y].value + "<br/>";
```

third,add class="tb"

```
objNewDiv.innerHTML = 'Textbox ' + intTextBox + ': <input type="text" 
id="tb_' + intTextBox + '" class="tb" name="tb_' + intTextBox + '"/>';
```

Comment: Thanks,  that helps now I am trying to make it so it generates two text boxes http://www.jsfiddle.net/xianshenglu/ev1f38L3/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code to output two separate text fields but to have it display together is not working.

```js
function display_array()
{
   var array=document.getElementsByClassName('tb');
   var e = "<hr/>";
var array2=document.getElementsByClassName('tb2');
  var e2 = "<hr/>";   
    
   for (var y=0; y<array.length; y++)
   {
     e += array[y].value ''+'' e2 += array2[y].value;
 // e2 += "Mac " + y + " = " + array2[y].value;
   }
document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = e + 'm' + e2;
//document.getElementById("Result2").innerHTML = e;
}
//Counter to maintain number of textboxes and give them unique id for later reference
var intTextBox = 0;
var intTextBox2 = 0;
/**
* Function to add textbox element dynamically
* First we incrementing the counter and creating new div element with unique id
* Then adding new textbox element to this div and finally appending this div to main content.
*/
function addElement() {
    intTextBox++;
 intTextBox2++;
    var objNewDiv = document.createElement('div');
    objNewDiv.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + intTextBox);
    objNewDiv.innerHTML = 'Textbox ' + intTextBox + ': <input type="text" id="tb_' + intTextBox + '" class="tb" name="tb_' + intTextBox + '"/>';
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(objNewDiv);
 
 
 var objNewDiv = document.createElement('div');
    objNewDiv.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + intTextBox);
    objNewDiv.innerHTML = 'Textbox1 ' + intTextBox + ': <input type="text" id="tb2_' + intTextBox + '" class="tb2" name="tb2_' + intTextBox + '"/>';
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(objNewDiv);
}
```

```html
<p>Demo of adding and removing textboxes dynamically using simple JavaScript</p>
<p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addElement();">Add</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeElement();">Remove</a>
</p>
<div id="content"></div><div id="content2"></div>


<input type="button" id="button2" value="Display" onclick="display_array();"></input>
<div id="Result"></div>
```